# Tamil letters scrambled & overlapped in xfce4 terminal

Tags: xubuntu, language-support, xfce4-terminal

Tamil progressively overlaps and combination letters (உயிர் மெய் எழுத்து) do not merge in Xfce4 terminal:

[image: terminal screenshot]

Changing font and encoding doesn't help. how to overcome this?

Comment: No good solution yet :( development on terminal emulators needed.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `fonts-lohit-taml` package, if you haven't already done so. Then create the file `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-prefer-tamil.conf` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
        <alias>
                <family>serif</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Tamil</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>sans-serif</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Tamil</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>monospace</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Tamil</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: still letters are scrambled..

Comment: @rajiniraja: Ok.. Maybe you want to try some other terminal emulator. `konsole`, which is default on KDE desktops, is said to work well with Indic scripts.

Comment: Yup, Konsole is the only emulator I know as of now that displays Tamil properly (supports Complex Text Layout). Worth mentioning that while it displays well (I can read files), input is still not perfect, because the cursor doesn't move enough for the letters.

Comment: is there any terminal emulator which reads and writes tamil letters in terminal well.